Properties pane for user defined agents
I'm pretty sure it is not possible to achieve what I am aiming for but I think it is still worth asking the community the question.
I am creating a new agent type named "Manoeuvre" which essentially consists of a list of PointNodes  that a vehicle should pass through to perform the "manoeuvre".  However at each PointNode in the list, I want to specify if the vehicle animation should change direction when it reaches that PointNode.
In my Agent definition, I have defined two Parameters:
PointNode node[]
Boolean reverseDirection[]


And I have defined the Control type as "One-dimensional array" to give me a nice array based element chooser in the properties window of the Manoeuvre agent:

Which produces the following resultant properties view:

However what I would really like is to be able pair up the "node" and "reverseDirection" fields so I can define an array of node-direction pairs when defining the Manoeuvre agent.
One way of getting close to the structure I want is to define a ManoeuvreNode class that is a container for PointNode - reverseDirection pairs and defining my Manoeuvre class as containing an array of ManoeuvreNodes however this doesn't achieve the properties window outcome I am chasing and requires me to define a heap of ManoeuvreNode objects just to be able to populate the list when I define a Manoeuvre object.
Does anyone have any thoughts on how I might be able to achieve the outcome I am seeking?

Is the change of direction defined by manoeuve only? For example, node1 can be a reverse_direction or not, depending on the sequence?
Or is there any other rule that could apply? For example, node1+car always reverse, but node1+truck never reverse. For example again, node1 to node2 always reverse, node1 to node3 never reverse.
If there is some rule, you could abstract the reverseDirection away and then the manoeuvre would only require the sequence of nodes

Impossible to achieve when you need nice property-window UI.
But otherwise, there are many ways such as using the Pair Java type, a custom Java class...
You can keep your current UI 1D-arrays and programmatically loop through them to create Pairs, maybe add sanity checks...
PS: Best alternative to retain easy UI: Load it from an xls file and let users define the pairs there. Load into any data structure you prefer and off you go

Thanks Ben, as I suspected.
I will take a look at the Pair type - I haven't come across this one before.
For now I have limited the number of reverse manoeuvres to one which means I don't need a list of manoeuvre nodes, just the one...  I'll see how that goes.
